# sh: 1: mix: not found - Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, laravel-mix, docker-container

I keep getting the following issue when trying to start up npm container within docker, I can't seem to figure out what is happening. It keeps attempting to start npm and then exits and doesn't run.

[image]

```
  | sh: 1: mix: not found
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! syscall spawn
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! file sh
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! @ watch-poll: `mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=3000`
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
    npm-aws         | npm ERR!
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm-aws         | 
    npm-aws         | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm-aws         | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-05T22_43_50_263Z-debug.log
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  testing-aws:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx-aws
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: mysql-aws
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_DATABASE: heatable
      MYSQL_USER: heatable
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - laravel
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: php-aws
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - laravel
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    container_name: composer-aws
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: npm.dockerfile
    container_name: npm-aws
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    command: npm run watch-poll
    networks:
      - laravel
    
  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: artisan-aws
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    links:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
```

npm.dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.17.1
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY ./src/package.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm clean-install
CMD npm run watch-poll
```

**UPDATE**

I've managed to resolve it by adding `tty: true`, see the updated:

```
  npm:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: npm.dockerfile
    container_name: npm-aws
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    networks:
      - laravel
```

I had to manually run `npm install` within the terminal of the container to get the node modules, if anyone knows a way of fixing without the manual inputted command. Please let me know :)

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]; if the problem is specifically in starting up the `npm-aws` containers, are the other containers' setups necessary?  The `volumes:` mount means that you're running code injected from the host instead of the code in the image, which can lead to inconsistencies in production, missing `node_modules` directories, and other problems; does removing the `volumes:` and the unnecessary `command:` help?

Comment: Looks like mix is not installed, or it's not in your `$PATH`.

Comment: @DavidMaze removing the `volumes:` and `command` i get the following now - `npm-aws exited with code 0`

Comment: @NickODell how do you set the $PATH within the docker?

Comment: @David Maze removing the `volumes:` does the trick, but that also means files in image will not be in sync with my host files. Any way to fix this?

Comment: If Docker's filesystem isolation is a problem, it's probably a one-liner to install Node directly on your host.  You can use host tools for development even if you're going to eventually deploy via Docker.